# How can I convert my provider into service?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a very simple applciation which allows a user to stream anime. However, I have a hard time working with provider. I almost understand how it works, but I have some questions.

I fetch all anime list from an api. It works flawlessly, but I want to separate my code into services and providers.

[image]

Here's my code:

## Code

### main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:test_provider/providers/anime.dart';

import 'models/anime_all.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AnimeTwistApiService(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Test',
        home: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Test'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              FutureBuilder(
                future: context.watch<AnimeTwistApiService>().getAllAnime(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<AnimeAll>> snapshot) {
                  List<Widget> list = List<Widget>();
                  for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
                    list.add(Text(snapshot.data[i].title.toString()));
                  }
                  return Column(
                    children: list,
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

### models/anime_all.dart

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

List<AnimeAll> animeAllFromJson(String str) =>
    List<AnimeAll>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => AnimeAll.fromJson(x)));

String animeAllToJson(List<AnimeAll> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class AnimeAll {
  AnimeAll({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.altTitle,
    this.season,
    this.ongoing,
    this.hbId,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.hidden,
    this.malId,
    this.slug,
  });

  int id;
  String title;
  String altTitle;
  int season;
  int ongoing;
  int hbId;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;
  int hidden;
  int malId;
  Slug slug;

  factory AnimeAll.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AnimeAll(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        altTitle: json["alt_title"] == null ? null : json["alt_title"],
        season: json["season"],
        ongoing: json["ongoing"],
        hbId: json["hb_id"] == null ? null : json["hb_id"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
        hidden: json["hidden"],
        malId: json["mal_id"] == null ? null : json["mal_id"],
        slug: Slug.fromJson(json["slug"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "alt_title": altTitle == null ? null : altTitle,
        "season": season,
        "ongoing": ongoing,
        "hb_id": hbId == null ? null : hbId,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
        "hidden": hidden,
        "mal_id": malId == null ? null : malId,
        "slug": slug.toJson(),
      };
}

class Slug {
  Slug({
    this.id,
    this.slug,
    this.animeId,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  int id;
  String slug;
  int animeId;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;

  factory Slug.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Slug(
        id: json["id"],
        slug: json["slug"],
        animeId: json["anime_id"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "slug": slug,
        "anime_id": animeId,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
      };
}
```

### providers/anime_twist.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_provider/models/anime_all.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AnimeTwistApiService extends ChangeNotifier {
  Future<List<AnimeAll>> getAllAnime() async {
    const String baseUrl = 'https://twist.moe/api/anime';

    final http.Response response = await http.get(baseUrl,
        headers: {'x-access-token': '1rj2vRtegS8Y60B3w3qNZm5T2Q0TN2NR'});

    return animeAllFromJson(response.body);
  }
}
```

It looks nice to  be honest, but I don't want to have my provider handle all of that. I would like to separate it into services and providers? How do I do it?

Comment: I don't understand why you use ChangeNotifier without notifying about a change :P I think you don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: I'm doing it from a tutorial: https://itnext.io/flutter-handling-your-network-api-calls-like-a-legend-using-provider-8c652c0530e3